# Rails ActiveRecord relationships, STI, and inheritance

Tags: activerecord, sti

OK, so it's been years since I've written any ruby code, and my design may be incorrect. With that in mind, I'm writing a small utility to clone project entities in TargetProcess via REST. Target Process has a data model that allows for several types of parent:child relationships:

```
project:epic:feature:user_story
project:feature:user_story
project:user_story
```

However, all the entities are nearly identical from a data structure perspective, so it seemed to make sense to use STI and use models to define the relationships and inheritance. I've created a new Rails app with only these models to verify the error I'm getting when I attempt to associate an Epic with a Feature:

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `epic_id`
```

Here are the models:

```
class TargetProcessEntity < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Project < TargetProcessEntity
  has_many :epics
  has_many :features
  has_many :user_stories
end

class Project < TargetProcessEntity
  has_many :epics
  has_many :features
end

class Epic < TargetProcessEntity
  belongs_to :project
  has_many   :features
end

class Feature < TargetProcessEntity
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :epic
  has_many   :user_stories
end

class UserStory < TargetProcessEntity
  belongs_to :feature
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Here is the schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150929122254) do

  create_table "epics", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",               null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",               null: false
    t.integer  "target_process_entity_id"
    t.integer  "project_id"
  end

  add_index "epics", ["project_id"], name: "index_epics_on_project_id"
  add_index "epics", ["target_process_entity_id"], name: "index_epics_on_target_process_entity_id"

  create_table "features", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "project_id"
    t.integer "epic_id"
    t.integer "target_process_entity_id"
  end

  add_index "features", ["epic_id"], name: "index_features_on_epic_id"
  add_index "features", ["project_id"], name: "index_features_on_project_id"
  add_index "features", ["target_process_entity_id"], name: "index_features_on_target_process_entity_id"

  create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",               null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",               null: false
    t.integer  "target_process_entity_id"
  end

  add_index "projects", ["id"], name: "index_projects_on_id"
  add_index "projects", ["target_process_entity_id"], name: "index_projects_on_target_process_entity_id"

  create_table "target_process_entities", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "type",             null: false
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "source_remote_id"
    t.float    "numeric_priority"
    t.integer  "owner"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
    t.integer  "cloned_remote_id"
    t.string   "resource_type"
    t.integer  "project_id"
  end

  create_table "user_stories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.integer  "feature_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",               null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",               null: false
    t.integer  "target_process_entity_id"
  end

  add_index "user_stories", ["feature_id"], name: "index_user_stories_on_feature_id"
  add_index "user_stories", ["project_id"], name: "index_user_stories_on_project_id"
  add_index "user_stories", ["target_process_entity_id"], name: "index_user_stories_on_target_process_entity_id"

end
```

While Epic and Feature both have a project_id, an instance of Feature does not have an epic_id attribute; attempting to assign an epic to feature blows up:

```
[20] pry(main)> epic = Epic.new
=> #<Epic:0x007fcab6c80590
 id: nil,
 type: "Epic",
 name: nil,
 description: nil,
 source_remote_id: nil,
 numeric_priority: nil,
 owner: nil,
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil,
 cloned_remote_id: nil,
 resource_type: "Epic",
 project_id: nil>
[21] pry(main)> feature = Feature.new
=> #<Feature:0x007fcab6d3ba48
 id: nil,
 type: "Feature",
 name: nil,
 description: nil,
 source_remote_id: nil,
 numeric_priority: nil,
 owner: nil,
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil,
 cloned_remote_id: nil,
 resource_type: "Feature",
 project_id: nil>
[22] pry(main)> epic.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "target_process_entities" ("type", "resource_type", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["type", "Epic"], ["resource_type", "Epic"], ["created_at", "2015-10-02 15:18:13.351578"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-02 15:18:13.351578"]]
   (4.6ms)  commit transaction
=> true
[23] pry(main)> feature.epic = epic
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `epic_id`
from /Users/kcallahan/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p647/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/attribute.rb:138:in `with_value_from_database'
[24] pry(main)>
```

I realize it is extremely possible I am either doing something wrong or have made a poor design decision; any input is hugely appreciated as I've not been able to find anything on this and have been banging my head against it for days!

Comment: I noticed that target_process_entities.project_id could be confusing; this maps to a Target Process project ID, not a local one. Changed this and suddenly assigning projects broke. Changed the schema again to have all the lookup ids on the main table and it works :/

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it working almost by mistake! I added the xxx_id columns to the target_process_entities table. I assumed that the STI tables would be able to respond to the relationship definitions, though my understanding of the inner workings of STI and relationships are rusty and incomplete at best...

Comment: new schema:

`create_table "target_process_entities", force: :cascade do |t|    t.string   "type",             null: false
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "source_remote_id"
    t.float    "numeric_priority"
    t.integer  "owner"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
    t.integer  "cloned_remote_id"
    t.string   "resource_type"
    t.integer  "target_process_project_id"
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.integer  "epic_id"
    t.integer  "feature_id"
    t.integer  "user_story_id"

  end`

Answer (score -1):

I may be wrong but it looks like your Feature table is a join table for many to many relationship between Project and Epic.

If that's the case, your models might look like this

```
class Project < TargetProcessEntity
  has_many :features
  has_many :epics, through: :features
end

class Epic < TargetProcessEntity
  has_many :features
  has_many :projects, through: :features
end

class Feature < TargetProcessEntity
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :epic
  has_many   :user_stories
end
```

the source is implied if you use the same name

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Interesting; I didn't think about it that way. An Epic though can only belong to a single Project. Additionally, while a Feature must belong to a Project, it also might belong to an Epic, if that level of hierarchy has been set up. Would a one-to-many Project:Epics disqualify the many-to-many through Features?

Comment: i think if you take out the has_many :projects, through: :features and replace with belongs_to: :project from Epic that should be fine. you just wouldn't access epics through features because it has it's own epics relationship